# how to break circular import in python

Tags: python, celery, circular-dependency

I have a circular import problem in my python code. The decorator from one module need to call a function in another module. And this function is using the decorator which is imported from previous module. The error message shows can't import name xxxx

my code structure:

```
__init__.py
worker1.py
worker2.py
...
```

and there is a decorator in **init**.py

```
def defer():
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapper_f(*args, **kargs):
            some logic here...
            new_func = eval("%s.apply_async" % func.func_name) # I use celery to do async call here
            new_func(args = args, kwargs = kargs)
        wrapper_f.__name__ = func.func_name # This is to allow celery to load different task based on function name
        return wrapper_f
    return wrapper
```

In worker1.py

```
@celery.task
@defer
def task1(*args, **kargs):
    some logic
```

It will have circular import in __init__.py and worker1.py, since **eval("%s.apply_async" % func.func_name)** need to load function in worker1, and worker1 need to load decorator in __init__. How can I solve this circular import problem?

Btw, I can't move the decorator function into worker1.py, bcz it is needed by other workers in the same folder.

Comment: move it to "decorators.py" or someat ...

Comment: I'm having a hard time following, but maybe you could move the import into the `wrapper_f` function

Comment: Why doesn't `defer()` take any arguments?

Comment: Where does the `apply_async` attribute come from?

Comment: The apply_async is from celery.

Comment: Thanks mgilson, to move the import into wrapper_f works. But I would like to find any cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: So, celery's decorator adds the attribute to the function?

Comment: If you exchange the order of the decorators you could avoid the `eval()` and just do: `new_func = func.apply_async`